# Snapping doesn't work when many layers loaded!

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, snapping

I am using Arcmap 10, when I have only limited number of layers loaded, the snapping experience is perfect but when I have many layers loaded specially polygons, snapping process is painful. My cursor turns to "Busy" shape (the sand clock) and can't snap to the feature. I have no idea why it happens. Any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What it takes to make Snapping sometimes become unusable in the way that you describe seems to depend on a number of factors, including the specification of your hardware, and the number and size of feature classes being displayed at the time.

My recommendations to avoid/alleviate the problem are:

- Try to use the highest specification hardware that you have available
- Turn off any layers that are not critical to your editing at the time
- Consider creating and using a subset of any large feature classes i.e. avoid state-wide datasets if you are only editing in a small project area
- Turn off any snapping types on your Snapping toolbar that you are not needing for the editing task at hand

Overall, try to keep your editing environment as uncluttered as possible.

I would not advocate reverting to **[classic snapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000047000000.htm)**, but that too is an option if you are desperate.